# I "accidentally" killed Kesh; can I still do "The Only Cure" quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In *Skyrim* (Xbox 360), I went to the Shrine of Peryite a while back, and Kesh was annoying me, so I killed him. Can I still start the quest "The Only Cure"? Or will I never be able to obtain that Daedric artifact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["The Only Cure" article on The Elder Scrolls Wiki](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/The_Only_Cure#Walkthrough) would suggest that it is possible to complete the quest even after killing Kesh (relevant emphasis added):

> Kesh tells the Dragonborn that in order to speak to [Peryite](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Peryite), they must:
>
> - Obtain a [silver ingot](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Silver_ingot)
> - Obtain a [deathbell](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Deathbell_(Skyrim)) flower
> - Obtain some [vampire dust](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Vampire_Dust_(Skyrim))
> - Obtain a [flawless ruby](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Flawless_ruby)
> - Give all of the acquired items to [Kesh](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Kesh)
> - Inhale the fumes
>
> After doing so, Peryite will appear to the Dragonborn as a spectral apparition […]
>
> **The quest can also be triggered by simply collecting the items needed (listed above) and going to the cauldron and activating it.** This will start the quest.

Comment: I havent even started the quest yet tho

Comment: You might be in trouble then. Try looking [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Only_Cure) if you haven't already.

Comment: I tried just gettig the materials and putting them in the pot, and it worked!!!!!!!!! It said "Started: The Only Cure" thanks for your help

Comment: FYI I just got the materials, put them in the pot and inhaled the fumes, and it worked! First link helped not second

Comment: Thanks for this! I couldn't find the answer for this anywhere else on the net! Saved my life!